# Mass Update filters on Reports

Tags: reports-api

We have about four Record Types in an Object, where we need to replace two Record Types with a new one.

There are more than a hundred reports which refers to these record types in filter conditions.

Is there a mass update feature where I can replace those old record types with the newer one?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing the record type then you can just change the label and it will not impact your existing reports.

> In a case of a record type, the label can be changed through the GUI
>   Interface. This will not impact the reports as they are automatically
>   updated once you run them.
>
> The Record type has a Label and another internal use field called
>   Record Type Name. Changing the label only changes how the field is
>   labeled as in reports etc.The internal name is used by Salesforce to
>   recognize and identify the specific record type.
>
> If you change the label, and not change the name, reports will not be
>   affected.

Comment: renaming does the work, but what if i need to add one more value in the filter condition for all those reports???

Comment: Yaa...If need to add filter then look into this. Using metadata i think we can only retrieve the report. but still you can have a look in following link : https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who finds this, take a look at this if you haven't already
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BIrsIAG

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.